# Why can we remove FC layers in VGGNet?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

From https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/:

> VGGNet. The runner-up in ILSVRC 2014 was the network from Karen Simonyan and Andrew Zisserman that became known as the VGGNet. Its main contribution was in showing that the depth of the network is a critical component for good performance. Their final best network contains 16 CONV/FC layers and, appealingly, features an extremely homogeneous architecture that only performs 3x3 convolutions and 2x2 pooling from the beginning to the end. Their pretrained model is available for plug and play use in Caffe. A downside of the VGGNet is that it is more expensive to evaluate and uses a lot more memory and parameters (140M). **Most of these parameters are in the first fully connected layer, and it was since found that these FC layers can be removed with no performance downgrade, significantly reducing the number of necessary parameters.**

What exactly is the author suggesting here? Is he suggesting both fully-connected layers can be removed leaving only the softmax layer or only one of the fully-connected layers can be removed? In either case, why? Is there a paper that argues this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is he suggesting both fully-connected layers can be removed leaving
>   only the softmax layer or only one of the fully-connected layers can
>   be removed?

Just the first FC layer can be removed.

> In either case, why?

It just happens that you can fit a model with less capacity -- that layer was just not needed to fit the data.

> Is there a paper that argues this?

There's no real argument that needs to be made here -- just the empirical evidence from later papers that newer architectures work well even without two FC layers.

Comment: "just the empirical evidence from later papers"
Do you have any citations for papers that show this?